# Invocar métodos dentro de uma ArrayList não reconhece o método do objeto

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, objetos, tipagem, arraylist

[image: Código]

[image: Código]

Eu tento invocar o método através do método `get().getNome()`, mas fala que o método não existe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aqui está a documentação da classe `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) que foi o tipo que usou para guardar objetos no `ArrayList`. Onde está o método `getNome()` nela? Se não tem você não pode chamar, ele não está disponível.

Você deve dizer que armazenou um objeto de um tipo mais específico chamado `JavaApplication6` que tem esse método. Mas o que vale é o tipo que está especificado no objeto principal. Quando você dá um `get(0)` o tipo de retorno desse método é o tipo que foi declarado na criação no objetos colocado em `perguntas`, conforme a [documentação desse método](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)) (note que ele é genérico, então o tipo `E` ali sempre será o que você declarou na criação do objeto. Se não entende isso, está fazendo coisas muito avançadas para o seu momento atual de conhecimento, volte um pouco para trás).

Como é certo que o objeto que tem ali é do tipo que deseja, poderia fazer um *cast* para transformar `Object` em `JavaApplication6`. Mas isso é errado na maioria das aplicações, vai te ensinar o erro, e provavelmente o erro cometido é o uso do `Object` quando na verdade queria usar o `JavaApplication6`. Se mudar isso o objeto que receberá será desse tipo e tem o método que deseja usar, e tudo ficará ok.

Eu daria um exemplo se não tivesse colocado o código como imagem.

Isso não resolve possíveis outros problemas que esteja cometendo na criação da classe.